# Add Items using CSV file - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am able to save products into my groups using the `group id`  using the `save function`
 but now i want to do that using an excel file. I am having issues with how to do that. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Controller**

```
 public function save($id, Request $request)
 {
    $group = Group::whereId($id)->firstorFail();
    $product = new Product(array(
        'name'  => $request->get('name'),
        'price' => $request->get('price'),
    ));

    $group->products()->save($product);
}

public function import($id, Request $request)
{
   $group = Group::whereId($id)->firstorFail();

   if($request->file('imported-file'))
   {
             $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
             $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
       {
             })->get();

       if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
       {
         foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
         {
           if(!empty($row))
           {
             $dataArray[] =
             [
               'name' => $row['name'],
               'price' => $row['price'],              
             ];
           }
       }

       if(!empty($dataArray))
       {
          Item::insert($dataArray);

        }
      }
    }

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('import/{id?}', 'ItemController@import');
```

Model for Product
**Product**

```
  public function groups()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group','group_product','product_id','group_id')
            ->withTimestamps();

       }
```

Model for group

**Group**

```
 public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','group_product','group_id','product_id')
  }
```

Comment: can you `var_dump($data->toArray())` and paste it here?

Comment: @madalinivascu, i am able to get my data but then i want to save the data under a group.  Can i do this   `$item->products()->save($dataArray);`
`

Comment: if you did the relationships right it should work https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: @madalinivascu, yes, my relation is correct. as you can see in my `save function` my relation works fine.  But in my `import`, the relation gives me this error `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given,`

Answer (score 0):

You need saveMany

```
$dataArray[] =
             new App\Product([
               'name' => $row['name'],
               'price' => $row['price'],              
             ]);

   $group->products()->saveMany($dataArray);
```

Comment: why is it throwing an error ` Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'` (SQL: insert into `item_product` (`item_id`, `created_at`, `product_id`, `name`, `price`, `updated_at`) values (20, 2017-11-14 12:36:31, 0, Fingerlin, 208110892, 2017-11-14 12:36:31)`

Comment: There is `column name` in the database but why?

Comment: check your product model

Comment: seems to be ok, are you sure you have a column named `name` in your `item_product` table?,try adding name and price to the fillable array of your product model

Comment: I don't have a column `name` in my `item_product`. The column `name` is in my `product` table.  If you look at my first comment, `the error` you see that there is `name, price`, both columns are in the product table

Comment: what's with the item model, you have a group model in the controller?,see my updated answer

Comment: Sorry its actually suppose to be item. `group` is typo.

Comment: But it doesn't matter since i have the corrections being made but the error still persist. My issue is,  i am able to save okay with the `save function` but why is the `import function` throwing the error that no column name